Responsive Timeline in Oracle APEX
I am designing an app in Oracle Apex and I need help implementing a concept. Basically, I want to open a timeline with the important dates I have marked for a specific object when it is selected.
Example: If I am talking about real estate construction X, I want the timeline to be able to show the start date, foundation date, construction survey, and completion date. If it is construction Y, I want it to do the same, but with its own dates.
Here are some additional details about the concept:
The timeline should be interactive, allowing users to navigate between different dates and view additional information for each date.
The timeline should be customizable, so that I can add and remove certain filters
I have a few ideas about how to implement this concept, such as adding CSS or HTML to my page, but I would appreciate any feedback or suggestions you may have.
Thank you for your time!

This is how I would approach this:

Install and study the 2 sample apps: "sample charts" and "sample calendar". Maybe what you need is already available as a standard component or a mix of standard components.
Study the UT (Universal Theme components) - there is a type of list called "Timeline" (https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/timeline-component) that could be relevant for you.

Once you have familiarized yourself with the available UI patterns (reports/charts/calendars) you can come up with a UI that works for your business case.
Note: Try to forget about "I can add my own css/html" initially. For beginning users that is tempting but the power of apex lies in what is available out of the box. Try to avoid custom css as much as possible - it quickly becomes a technical debt that needs to be checked on every update.
